# Add several variables to a data frame depending on a rule from another data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

this is an example of what my data look like (both are data.frames):

table 1:

```
0_x 1_x 2_x .... 20_x
cat cat red......green
dog red green     cat
bee blue bee....  dog
........
```

and table 2

```
  x    name       code
cat    animals     1
dog    animals     1
bee    animals.    1
green  colours     2
red    colours.    2
...
```

the result I want to obtain its the following:

```
0_y 1_y 2_y .... 20_y  0_x 1_x 2_x .... 20_x
1    1    2.....  2    cat cat red......green
1    2    2       1    dog red green     cat
1    2    1....   1    ....
........
```

basically table 2 contains a rule I want use to create variables to add to table 1
if 0_x is a cat I want 0_y equal to 1 (because in table 2 cat = 1)

how can I obtain this result in an elegant way? (If I only had a variable 0_x I would just do a merge, but here I have several]

Comment: Curious, why do you want that wide formatted data structure? Most data science needs (merging, appending, aggregation, modeling, plotting) are best done in long, tidy format.

Comment: @Parfait I basically wanted to relabel a series of categorical variables (sharing the same structure) I am using for a model into less categories according to a parent-son relationship I have on another file (cats, dogs and so on are animals etc.) I have way too many categories in comparison to the number of observations I have at the moment and I wanted to find a way to use this information a meaningful way. Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match your values between the table 2 `x` column and the column you are reading. Here is an example where I use this in a for-loop.

Note : consider that colnames of df1 must be with a letter first and not a number. And that I use character strings.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x_0 = c('cat','dog','bee'), 
                  x_1 = c('cat','red','blue') , 
                  x_2 = c('red','green','bee') )

df2 <- data.frame(x = c('cat','dog','bee','green','red','blue'),
                 name = c('animals','animals','animals','colours','colours','colours'),
                 code = c(1,1,1,2,2,2))

df1b = df1 ; colnames(df1b) <- sub("x","y",colnames(df1b))
df3 = cbind(df1b,df1)

for(i in 1:ncol(df1)){
  df3[,i] <- df2$code[match(df1[,i],df2$x)]
}
df3
#   y_0 y_1 y_2 x_0  x_1   x_2
# 1   1   1   2 cat  cat   red
# 2   1   2   2 dog  red green
# 3   1   2   1 bee blue   bee
```

Comment: would need to change to df3 = cbind(df1b,df1) , part that it works perfectly

Comment: Thx it's edited. The first code I intended to put didn't include the colnames modifications, so `df3  = cbind(df1,df1)` made more sens.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the following base R solution, using `match()` + `unlist()`

```
df1post <- df1
df1[] <- df2$code[match(unlist(df1),df2$x)]
dfout <- cbind(`names<-`(df1,gsub("_x","_y",names(df1))),df1post)
```

such that

```
> dfout
  0_y 1_y 2_y 20_y 0_x  1_x   2_x  20_x
1   1   1   2    2 cat  cat   red green
2   1   2   2    1 dog  red green   cat
3   1  NA   1    1 bee blue   bee   dog
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- structure(list(`0_x` = c("cat", "dog", "bee"), `1_x` = c("cat", 
"red", "blue"), `2_x` = c("red", "green", "bee"), `20_x` = c("green", 
"cat", "dog")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(x = c("cat", "dog", "bee", "green", "red"), name = c("animals", 
"animals", "animals.", "colours", "colours."), code = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```